# How to handle overlapping mouse input in GUI?

Tags: c#, algorithm, user-interface, xna

We are developing a GUI system.
How can we handle the input of front panel, if it has also a panel under it? I mean, if i click on the front panel, the mouse input also effects on the lower panel. How can i avoid it? We searched that problem on the net. For example, z-indexing systems or layering systems. But they are not ended up well. There are not much resources about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Boolean to check if your panel is active. When another panel is clicked set last panel to false and the new panel clicked to true.

Then when clicking use the Boolean and only do the code fore mouse click on the panel that comes up active.

Answer (score 0):

Search through the reverse ordering that you do to draw them. The first ones you draw are on the bottom, the last ones you draw are on top. So the last ones you draw should be the first ones you search through for input.